# Can I increase the dahlia tubers yield using the following method?

Tags: propagation, bulbs

I bought four potted dahlias (for some reason, they sell better than tubers so it's harder than before to find tubers and I find potted plants instead).

I read this article about propagating dahlias from cuttings, from the American Dahlia Society, see Link here: [Dahlias: Success with cuttings](https://www.dahlia.org/docsinfo/articles/success-with-cuttings/)

This page shows how to fix symptom # 4 in the list of possible symptoms. My question, can I use this method to increase the number of tubers the shrub can form without taking any cuttings? The idea I have in mind is to let the dahlia grow a longer stalk, and then plant it **deeper** into the soil, covering few more nodes at the bottom. If my guess is correct, I should get a tuber at each node. Am I correct?